# Swift 3: Which is better for webservice calls? URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:URL) OR session.dataTask(with: request)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsurlsession

Swift 3:
I am trying to understand the difference between the 2 approaches to make network calls, and if one is better than the other in terms of performance or any other parameter. 
I have tested both approaches and results are the same. Trying to implement best practises/ most commonly followed 'style' .

```
let url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getrecent&api_key=APIKEY&extras=url_h,date_taken&format=json&nojsoncallback=1"
```

**Approach 1:** `dataTaskwithURL`

```
  let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (theData, theResponse, theError) in

     })
    task.resume()
```

**Approach 2:** `dataTaskwithRequest with NSURLSession(configuration: config)`

```
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

})
task.resume()
```

Many books/blogs have their own theory to use one of the 2 approaches

Comment: You are using Swift 3. You should use `URLSession`, not `NSURLSession`.

Comment: Good point, made the changes

Comment: you webserverice dealt with post and get methods the datataskwithrequest will be recommended else you can use datataskwith url